# How can I fix this ValueError in sin this code?

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
decode=encoder.fit(clas_data)
Y_clas = encoder.fit_transform(clas_data)
#print(Y_clas)
df.head()
```

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([480.0, 480.0, 415.69, 505.0, 480.0, 336.9, 480.0, 492.03, 480.0,
       480.0, 505.0, 336.9, 556.08, 415.69, 336.9, 556.08, 492.03, 492.03,
       556.08, 480.0, 480.0, 415.69, 556.08, 480.0, 492.03, 480.0, 492.03,
       415.69, 556.08, 556.08, 505.0, 556.08, 556.08, 415.69, 480.0,
       480.0, 505.0, 556.08, 415.69, 480.0, 480.0, 336.9, 505.0, 480.0,
       480.0, 556.08, 480.0, 480.0, 336.9, 415.69, 480.0, 556.08, 480.0,
       480.0, 556.08, 492.03, 480.0, 505.0, 480.0, 556.08, 556.08, 556.08,
       480.0, 556.08, 336.9, 480.0, 492.03, 336.9, 556.08, 480.0, 480.0,
       415.69, 415.69, 480.0, 505.0, 415.69, 556.08, 415.69, 415.69,
       556.08, 556.08, 505.0, 505.0, 556.08, 492.03, 505.0, 556.08,
       492.03, 336.9, 480.0, 556.08, 480.0, 480.0, 480.0, 556.08, 415.69,
       505.0, 480.0, 556.08, 492.03, 415.69, 556.08, 505.0, 415.69,
       415.69, 505.0], dtype=object),)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include some details as to what you are doing.  What is the input?  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: 1. I am doing conflict prediction based on some variables I have as input. Among those variables, one column (Revenue) you can see in the ValueError.

2. The error traceback is on the line: 

decode=encoder.fit(clas_data)

Comment: What is ```clas_data```?